# Difference in array syntaxes in postgres

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between the following two ways to define an array?

```
select '{1, 2, 3, 4}', ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4];
```

For example the docs gives the following two examples:

```
-- An array value can be replaced completely:

UPDATE sal_emp SET pay_by_quarter = '{25000,25000,27000,27000}'
    WHERE name = 'Carol';

-- or using the ARRAY expression syntax:

UPDATE sal_emp SET pay_by_quarter = ARRAY[25000,25000,27000,27000]
    WHERE name = 'Carol';
```

Are there any differences between these two forms? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html

Comment: Also answered in here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161301/array-stringifies-to-using-in-postgres-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Both result in the same array value.

One advantage of the `array[]` constructor syntax is, that the elements can be written with the usual syntax for SQL literals. E.g. `array['One String', 'Other String']` vs. `{"One String", "Other String"}'`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)

> Notice that the array elements are ordinary SQL constants or expressions; for instance, string literals are single quoted, instead of double quoted as they would be in an array literal.

Comment: but they're not quite the same when I was testing. For example: `select array[1]||array[2], '{1}'||'{2}'` produces two different values.

Comment: Seems to require explicit casting for them to be treated the same, for example: `'{1}'::int[]||'{2}'::int[]`.